# mysql_num_rows PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

```
elseif(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // Look for their user
    $lookuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='". mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."'");
    // If we find a row
    if(mysql_num_rows($lookuser) > 0)
```

But my else for that, echos: `An error has occured. <br> If you are sure you entered your username correctly, please contact an administrator.`

I've tried to echo `$_POST['username'];` all works out fine. I've made sure my user exists, that works out fine.

The PHP error I get: 
`Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in password.php on line 23`

Comment: You are not doing any error checking in your query. Why not? It's no wonder it breaks with that error if the query fails. This reference question shows how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6198104/reference-what-is-a-perfect-code-sample-using-the-mysql-extension

Comment: Maybe a bit more code would help.

Comment: Have you echoed mysql_error()? $lookuser = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='". mysql_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Sidenote: use mysql_real_escape_string() at least,if you want to stick to the mysql_* family

Comment: @RichBradshaw what more code would you need? The error is pretty clear

Comment: Do not use `mysql_escape_string()`, it is deprecated because it does not work properly. Use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP / MYSSQL error: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995001/php-myssql-error-mysql-num-rows-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid)

Comment: Better yet, don't use mysql_* at all -- it's all ancient, and barely supported.  mysqli does everything mysql does, plus it offers support for prepared statements (which make escaping unnecessary for most use cases).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an error in your sql query. To be sure of that, echo after your mysql_query `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 1):

[Php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) says this about the return value of mysql_query:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

If you're getting a boolean, it's because there's a mysql error.  Use [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to print the error, it'll help you diagnose the issue.